# Run PHP script(to create file) using cmd

Tags: php, cmd

I m trying to run php script using cmd

CMD Code

```
"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php.exe" -f "C:\wamp\www\file\test.php"
```

PHP Code

```
$fileLocation = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . "/file/myfile.txt";//OR $fileLocation = "myfile.txt"
$file = fopen($fileLocation,"w");
$content = "Your text here";
fwrite($file,$content);
fclose($file);
```

Here problem is file is not created. If I run this file in browser then file is generate. user is administrator .

Comment: I don't think `getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT")` renders anything useful... Echo that value and check if the result is what you were hoping it to be.

Answer (score 1):

To run php code try this command:

```
php -f yourfilename.php
```

if you are in different location than specify absolute path. This will only work when you set your environment variable properly.

Comment: replace '/file/myfile.txt' to '\file\myfile.txt' than it will work.
actually it can not able to find the path of file.

Comment: set environment variable and your cmd type  php  -q   pathtophpfile/yourfile.php

Comment: I run this on my localhost and its working properly.
Code was like
$file = fopen('D:\xampp\htdocs\file\hello.txt','w');

i faced problem when i assign path to a php variable.